# Internet Explorer, Typescript and Webpack Issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, webpack

i have an issue with IE11 and lower. My application written in typescript with this tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
"sourceMap": true,
"jsx": "react",
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"strictNullChecks": true,
"lib": [
  "es6",
  "es2015",
  "dom"
],
"experimentalDecorators": true
},
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

Also i have a couple of chunks, transpiled by webpack - vendors, common and apps. In source i have some files, which shared between every chunk and apps. This files contains common code(such as http functions, loggers and etc.).

Main problem is that the IE 11 and lower can't find this common function inside apps. For example in chunk 'common' i have 'request' async function, which returns Promise, and in IE 11 i have errors, like

```
'Object doesn't support property or method "request"'
```

In every normal browser everything works, but the IE isn't normal browser